# How to prevent YouTube from using built-in Browser?

Tags: javascript, php, android

Is there a way to prevent the YouTube app on Android from opening links with the built in browser and use the full-sized Chrome app? I'm using PHP on the web server.

Since that built-in browser has a lot of compatibility problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: No, you can't.

YouTube has chosen to open links in their app with a library called [Chrome Custom Tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs). (as alternative to open them direly in Chrome).

Chrome Custom Tabs doesn't offer anyway to open links directly in chrome with the current version.

YouTube does check before opening if an app is installed that can handle the event (e.g. Twitter app for all Twitter URLs). But I don't think that is an alternative for you.

It properly would be best to fix the website as best as possible for this scenario.

Comment: What i mean is, if for example, i add my website's link on a youtube video description, and then if yhe user clicks on that link, if there is a way that when my website opens, it redirect users to their default browser and not the youtube browser, i hope i made myself more clear now

Comment: @hellothere yes, I misunderstood you. Unfortunately this isn't possible either

Comment: are 100% sure? or should i also wait for someone's else answer?

Comment: @hellothere Unfortunately, I am. I changed the answer a bit to explain it.